# create condition in <html:optionsCollection> tag in struts

Tags: java, struts

I am displaying 3 values from a collection in a table of 3 rows i.e "aa,bb,cc" using `<html:optionsCollection>` tag in struts.

```
aa    can edit
bb    cannot edit
cc    can edit
```

There is a condition that value bb is not editable.
How to do that in struts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved with `<logic:notEqual>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JSTL conditions `<c:if>` in your `<html:optionsCollection>` tag.